# Emacs autocomplete error : running timer

Tags: emacs, autocomplete

I tryed to install autocomplete mode for emacs, downloaded it from the elpa repository, with

```
M-x list-packages
```

And when I try it, the mode gives me an error

> Error running timer ‘ac-update-greedy’: (error "Keyword argument :max-width not one of (:min-height :around :face :mouse-face :selection-face :scroll-bar :margin-left :margin-right :symbol :parent :parent-offset :keymap)")
>
> Error running timer ‘ac-show-menu’: (error "Keyword argument :max-width not one of (:min-height :around :face :mouse-face :selection-face :scroll-bar :margin-left :margin-right :symbol :parent :parent-offset :keymap)")

And it fails even if I don't load each other mod. Even If I manually run

```
M-x  auto-complete-mode
```

Where can this error come from ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer. So I'll just post it there in case somebody is in the same situation,

The problem came from popup.el, a required package for auto-complete. 
I downloaded the sources, recompiled them, and added the new popup.el in my mod folder

And it worked !

Comment: Nice solution! I'm facing a similar problem. When I update auto-complete package, popup package is not out of date. After update popup package, all works well.